# Swift UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, swift, safari, uiactivityviewcontroller

Could anyone tell me how to implement "Open in Safari" in UIActivityViewController? I know this questions is a duplicate of another question posted a long time ago, and the method at that time was by using a framework that can no longer be used.

The data I am sharing is a URL. I already have a fully working ActivityVC and I only need to add that “open in safari” button.

Thank you very much.

code:

```
@IBAction func shareButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [URL(string: urlStr)!], applicationActivities: nil)
    activityVC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
    self.present(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Try this Link if it meets your requirement https://bjartes.wordpress.com/2015/02/19/creating-custom-share-actions-in-ios-with-swift/

Comment: Yes it works, thank you very much. BTW do you happen to have any Safari icon images?

Comment: If that link helped you shall I post this as answer ? And I didn't get you safari icon image ?

Comment: Yes it worked. Please post your answer. I found the images, thank you very much.

Comment: I posted that as answer, Thanks You Can accept it and close this thread

Comment: hmmmm i accepted the answer but how do I close this thread..

Comment: That get closed automatically when you accept an answer, Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this Link if it meets your requirement

Link - https://bjartes.wordpress.com/2015/02/19/creating-custom-share-actions-in-ios-with-swift/

**Code Required**

```
class FavoriteActivity: UIActivity {
    override func activityType() -> String? {
        return "TestActionss.Favorite"
    }

    override func activityTitle() -> String? {
        return "Add to Favorites"
    }

    override func canPerformWithActivityItems(activityItems: [AnyObject]) -> Bool {
        NSLog("%@", __FUNCTION__)
        return true
    }

    override func prepareWithActivityItems(activityItems: [AnyObject]) {
        NSLog("%@", __FUNCTION__)
    }

    override func activityViewController() -> UIViewController? {
        NSLog("%@", __FUNCTION__)
        return nil
    }

    override func performActivity() {
        // Todo: handle action:
         NSLog("%@", __FUNCTION__)

        self.activityDidFinish(true)
    }

    override func activityImage() -> UIImage? {
        return UIImage(named: "favorites_action")
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
@IBAction func showAvc(sender: UIButton) {
        let textToShare = "Look at this awesome website!"
        let myWebsite = NSURL(string: "http://www.google.com/")!

        let objectsToShare = [textToShare, myWebsite]
        let applicationActivities = [FavoriteActivity()]

        let avc = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: objectsToShare, applicationActivities: applicationActivities)

        self.presentViewController(avc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

You need to implement your own activity, please check the code below.

```
import UIKit

final class SafariActivity: UIActivity {
    var url: URL?

    override var activityImage: UIImage? {
        return UIImage(named: "SafariActivity")!
    }

    override var activityTitle: String? {
        return NSLocalizedString("Open in Safari", comment:"")
    }

    override func canPerform(withActivityItems activityItems: [Any]) -> Bool {
        for item in activityItems {
            if
                let url = item as? URL,
                UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url)
            {
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
    }

    override func prepare(withActivityItems activityItems: [Any]) {
        for item in activityItems {
            if
                let url = item as? URL,
                UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url)
            {
                self.url = url
            }
        }
    }

    override func perform() {
        var completed = false

        if let url = self.url {
            completed = UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
        }

        activityDidFinish(completed)
    }
}

let url = URL(string: "http://www.apple.com")!

let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [url], applicationActivities: [SafariActivity()])
present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 3):

**Updated to Swift 5.1 & iOS 13**

Bonus:

- `ActivityType` extension to use with `.excludedActivityTypes`.
- `UIImage(systemName:)` to use SF Symbols plus `.applyingSymbolConfiguration` to take advantage of its flexibility.

To improve:

- Implement completion handler on `UIApplication.shared.open` to handle errors (unlikely to occur).

```swift
import UIKit

extension UIActivity.ActivityType {
    static let openInSafari = UIActivity.ActivityType(rawValue: "openInSafari")
}

final class SafariActivity: UIActivity {

    var url: URL?

    var activityCategory: UIActivity.Category = .action

    override var activityType: UIActivity.ActivityType {
        .openInSafari
    }

    override var activityTitle: String? {
        "Open in Safari"
    }

    override var activityImage: UIImage? {
        UIImage(systemName: "safari")?.applyingSymbolConfiguration(.init(scale: .large))
    }

    override func canPerform(withActivityItems activityItems: [Any]) -> Bool {
        activityItems.contains { $0 is URL ? UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL($0 as! URL) : false }
    }

    override func prepare(withActivityItems activityItems: [Any]) {
        url = activityItems.first { $0 is URL ? UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL($0 as! URL) : false } as? URL
    }

    override func perform() {
        if let url = url {
            UIApplication.shared.open(url)
        }
        self.activityDidFinish(true)
    }

}
```

Comment: Great call on SF Symbols! Love this!